# Lists append in a list in for loop

Tags: python

In Python, I cannot create a list in which every item is a different list. 
This is an example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = []
c = []

for i in a:
  b.append(i)
  c.append(b)
c
```

the result is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

instead, what I would reach is:

```
[[1],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

May you please help me?

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `c.append(b[:])`?

Comment: You need to make a copy of `b` before or after you modify it, and append the copy. Otherwise all elements are references to the same list, which you keep updating.

Comment: `res = [[i for i in range(1,j+1)] for j in i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Python`, variables holds `references` to the `Objects`. When you append your list `b` to another list `c`, you basically copy the reference of `b` to your list `c` (NOT THE OBJECT'S CONTENT). Since, list are mutuable, when you modify your list `b` (after appending it to list `c`), it's updated value will also be reflected in `c`.

Try this code to learn more:

```
a = [10]
c = a
a.append(100)
print(c)
```

Outputs:

```
[10, 100]
```

You can either do:

```
c.append(b[:])
```

OR

```
c.append(list(b))
```

OR

You can also use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) in Python.

```
import copy
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = []
c = []

for i in a:
    b.append(i)
    c.append(copy.deepcopy(b))
print(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing `c.append(b)` you're putting *the* b instance, so b is everywhere in c, and as you fill `b` you see it in all boxes of `c`, you need to make a copy with on these ways

```
c.append(list(b))
c.append(b[:])
```

---

Regarding the task itself, I'd propose another way to do it:

```
for end in a:
    c.append(list(range(1, end + 1)))
```

Which corresponds to `c = [list(range(1, end + 1)) for end in a]` in list comprehension